# Timers as Sleep?

Tags: vb.net

I've looked around a lot and have found some answers to this but none of them work.

I understand that "Sleep()" freezes the application, that's why I added a timer. I want it to sleep 1000 milliseconds so I did this:

```
Timer1.Interval = 1000
Timer1.Start()
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I get no errors and the program runs just like it would have ran if I didn't have the timer.

Am I doing this right? if not can someone fix it up? (the timer is enabled)

Thanks!

Comment: `Timer1` will fire an event every 1000ms;  they dont sleep.  You must have missed this when looking around:  [Timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: All you have done is start the timer. Your code will continue with the instruction after `Timer1.Start()`. You need to exit this method, and then in the `Timer1.Tick` event you can do what you need to do to restart processing.

Comment: I think what you might want is `await Task.Delay(1000)`

Comment: Have you looked into `Thread.Sleep(1000)`? [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen to the Tick Event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.90).aspx

Create a handler and keep track of the ticks with:

```
'prompts the user whether the timer should continue to run'
Private Shared Sub TimerEventProcessor(ByVal myObject As Object, _
                                       ByVal myEventArgs As EventArgs) _
                                   Handles myTimer.Tick
    myTimer.Stop()

    ' Displays a message box asking whether to continue running the timer. 
    If MessageBox.Show("Continue running?", "Count is: " & alarmCounter, _
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then 
        ' Restarts the timer and increments the counter.
        alarmCounter += 1
        myTimer.Enabled = True 
    Else 
        ' Stops the timer.
        exitFlag = True 
    End If 
End Sub
```

and in your main

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    ' Adds the event and the event handler for the method that will 
    ' process the timer event to the timer. 

    ' Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.
    myTimer.Interval = 5000
    myTimer.Start()

    ' Runs the timer, and raises the event. 
    While exitFlag = False 
        ' Processes all the events in the queue.
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While 

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this easily translates to VB, but for the OP sake can you put this in VB syntax in which the question tag was marked?

Comment: So this will make the console wait but at the same time let the other code keep running?

Comment: I am unsure exacly what cenario you need but yes, All other working threads and anything IN the while loop will continue to run. Anything after the while loop will not run until the variable is switched. But TimerEventProcessor() will only fire once every 5 seconds in this example. The while loop, keeps things in place while it waits for the timer to set `exitFlag` to `true` then when exit flag does change, it will execute anything UNDER the while loop.

Comment: If you just want things to run no matter what, you could remove the while loop. :)

Comment: @Obfuscated were you able to figure it out? Do you have anymore questions? I am willing to update my answer to more of a specific solution if you could clarify exactly what you are trying to do with an example?

Comment: @Rosenumber14 Your solution was great and helped me figure out just what I needed. Thank you so much!